# Task Scheduler in Windows not working for laravel

Tags: windows, laravel, cron, taskscheduler

Laravel application is hosted in windows server, hence created a task using Task Scheduler which runs every 1 minute.

Task is used to run a program which is saved in a file named `cron.bat`, of which the contents are

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot

C:\php\php.exe artisan schedule:run >> .\storage\logs\cron.log 2>&1
```

However when the task is run, an entry is logged into the `cron.log` file but none of the commands associated with the task is executed. I do not see any error logs in `laravel.log` file

But when I change the `cron.bat` file contents to

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot

C:\php\php.exe artisan command:name
```

It executes the respective command.

Why would this happen? I have given Full Control to all the files and folders in `wwwroot` and `cron.bat` file which resides in `wwwroot`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954322/14344959 I hope this one helps to you